# How to multiply XML values in an XML table?

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

XML table  (as rendered in Firefox 47.0.1)

[image: How the XML table renders]

The .XML file doesn't contain nodes for Total Price, but I can still derive it in the XML table by multiplying PRICE * QUANTITY.

I am aware of this solution:

```
y[i].getElementsByTagName("PRICE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue * y[i].getElementsByTagName("QUANTITY")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

However I would like to multiply variables instead:

```
p * q
```

So I have already declared variables for PRICE and QUANTITY (p and q):

```
var p = y[i].getElementsByTagName("PRICE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
var q = y[i].getElementsByTagName("QUANTITY")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

But this only yields the correct result for the first row (Unit 1).

Why is this not working?

Here's my example.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CUSTOMER_ORDER>
    <UNIT>
        <NAME>Unit 1</NAME>
        <QUANTITY>45</QUANTITY>
        <PRICE>25.99</PRICE>
    </UNIT>
    <UNIT>
        <NAME>Unit 2</NAME>
        <QUANTITY>209</QUANTITY>
        <PRICE>9.95</PRICE>
    </UNIT>
    <UNIT>
        <NAME>Unit 3</NAME>
        <QUANTITY>80</QUANTITY>
        <PRICE>14.99</PRICE>
    </UNIT>
    <UNIT>
        <NAME>Unit 4</NAME>
        <QUANTITY>156</QUANTITY>
        <PRICE>35.88</PRICE>
    </UNIT>
    <UNIT>
        <NAME>Unit 5</NAME>
        <QUANTITY>25</QUANTITY>
        <PRICE>199.00</PRICE>
    </UNIT>
</CUSTOMER_ORDER>
```

Here's my test html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
  table,
  th,
  td {
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  th,
  td {
    padding: 5px;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <body onload="loadXMLDoc()">

  <table id="test"></table>

  <script>
    function loadXMLDoc() {
      var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
          testFunction(xmlhttp);
        }
      };
      xmlhttp.open("GET", "example.xml", true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }

function testFunction(xml) {
var i;
var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
var table="<tr><th>Unit</th><th>Price</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Total Price</th></tr>";
var y = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("UNIT");
for (i = 0; i > y.length; i++);
var p = y[i].getElementsByTagName("PRICE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;  
var q = y[i].getElementsByTagName("QUANTITY")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue; 
for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++)
{
table += "<tr><td>" +
y[i].getElementsByTagName("NAME")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
"</td><td>" +
y[i].getElementsByTagName("PRICE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
"</td><td>" +
y[i].getElementsByTagName("QUANTITY")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
"</td><td>" +
p * q + // This is the total price column yielding 1169.55 across all rows.
"</td></tr>";
      }
      document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = table;
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, the link simply goes to an image. All relevant code is in the question itself.

Comment: So, for this one, look into the `parseFloat` function. That will get your the numeric value of those values. Then just add them together.

Comment: What does this question have to do with XPath? You're accessing the nodes using DOM methods, but that part already works. Did you want to change that part to use XPath instead?

Comment: Thanks. I want the simplest solution. I'm almost there, though help would be appreciated.

Comment: `y[i].getElementsByTagName("PRICE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue * y[i].getElementsByTagName("QUANTITY")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be syntax and the solution is very simple. Thanks to everyone who contributed their input.

You can see the final testfunction(xml) here:

```
function testFunction(xml) {
var i;
var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
var table="<tr><th>Unit</th><th>Price</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Total Price</th></tr>";
var y = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("UNIT");
for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) 
{
var p = y[i].getElementsByTagName("PRICE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
var q = y[i].getElementsByTagName("QUANTITY")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
var n = y[i].getElementsByTagName("NAME")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

table += "<tr><td>" +
n +
"</td><td>" +
p +
"</td><td>" +
q +
"</td><td>" +
p*q + // This is the total price column. 
"</td></tr>";
}
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = table;
}
```